# calling php page and executing JavaScript on that page

Tags: php, jquery

I am generating pdf (TCPDF) from html and the pdf needs to have a stacked bar chart within it. For the chart I have created a page chart.php and added following code on it, which creates the chart and also outputs the chart as an image, then using the jquery post I save the image on the server (chart.php) :

```
<?php
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST["picture"])) {
        $t = time();
        $data = base64_decode($_POST['picture']);
        file_put_contents('img/'.$t.'.jpg', $data);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="imgForm" action="" method="post">

        <div style="width:800px;height:450px;">
            <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>

            <img id="canvasimage" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [{
                barPercentage: 0.5,
                barThickness: 6,
                maxBarThickness: 8,
                minBarLength: 2,
                data: [5, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
                backgroundColor: ["red", "blue", "green", "blue", "red", "blue"]
            }]

        }

        function done() {

            var url = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/jpg");
            document.getElementById("canvasimage").src = url;

            var image = $('#canvasimage').attr('src');
            var base64ImageContent = image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('picture', base64ImageContent);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData
            }).done(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
        var options = {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                    beginAtZero: true
                }]
            },
            animation: {
                onComplete: done
            }
        };


        var myBarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data,
            options: options
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there a way I can execute this page from another php page ? so that this page (chart.php) gets called in the background and it saves the image ?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

**EDIT** :

This is how I am calling the chart.php page

```
$("#btntest").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : 'chart.php',
            }).done(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        });
```

my console.log(e) shows the entire chart.php page in html format.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I'm not sure what you mean but you can specifiy url: {url} in your $.ajax request.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld thanks for the reply, I already have the url specified. See the updated question.

Comment: Aha. What response you're looking for? What do you want the PHP to send back?

Comment: not expecting anything, I just want the code on chart.php page to execute. the chart.php page when run should create a chart in the canvas tag and then from there when the chart is loaded (done method is called) and within the done method I am doing a post to the same chart page which saves the image of the chart on the server. 
If I open the chart.php page on my browser it works fine but the ajax call from another page doesn't do anything

Comment: the ajax request does just basically execute the PHP-page and you get back som kind of response. Are you only looking for the user to get back to chart.php when everything is processed?

Comment: no I am generating a pdf file which is going to include an image (this image is of the chart). The pdf file is working fine, now I cannot add canvas tag to the pdf generating page (TCPDF) which has its limitations. So what I am planning to do make an ajax call to this chart.php page and then import the created image from the server.